# Unable to print HTML output on new line using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print the following output onto my html page:

100.101.102.103

Trying 192.168.30.61 ... Open

Warning Notice

This system is restricted solely to company authorized users

---

But instead i am getting this :
'\n100.101.102.103\r\nTrying 100.101.102.103 ... Open\r\n\r\n*************                       **************************************************************\r\n                                              Warning Notice\r\n\r\nThis system is restricted solely to company authoriz                       ed users

---

The JS:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/runCommand_query',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
            //alert("hi");
            console.log(response);
            //$("#opt").html(response);
            $("#opt").html(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    $("#opt").val(error);
        }
    });
});
```

});

The HTML:

```
output id="opt" name="opt"
```

I need a solution to get rid of the "\r" and "\n"

Comment: You missed the brackets <> around the output tag in your snippet.

Comment: Ya i may have missed them while writing this question but not in the actual html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the JavaScript string escape code for a new line to an HTML `<br>` element.

At the beginning of your AJAX success handler, add:

```
response = response.replace(/(\n|\r)/g, "<br>");
```

Here's an example:

```js
var response = " '\n100.101.102.103\r\nTrying 100.101.102.103 ...";

response = response.replace(/(\n|\r)/g, "<br>");

document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = response;
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Beat me to it ;)

Comment: I have come across one more issue. Wondering if you could help:
In the below XML example, i only want to print the plain text,which is **Line Card-1** and **ABC123**, without the line breaks. 

`
<rack>\n <rack-name>Line Card-1</rack-name>\n <chassis>\n <serial-number>ABC123</serial-number>\n </chassis>\n </rack>\n </racks>\n </diag>\n </data>\n</rpc-reply>\n
`
using the same JS above, how do i modify it to print output without substituting \n by <br> for XML syntax? I am assuming I would need an **if** statement